# Revert changes from a git branch to the master branch

Tags: git, github

Im working in the language Ruby on rails, I have create a branch called user-micropost. Inside this branch i have created files, modified files and done database migrations.

I have messed up somewhere, so i would like to restore the code that it is currently on GitHub, or return the code to the state from before creating this new branch.

Would it be sufficient to do:

`git checkout master` and then `git branch -d branch-name`?

Or that will only delete the branch but not revert the changes?

I havent commited, so all the changes are local on the IDE. (im using AWS Cloud9 IDE)

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not execute `git add <file>` (all your changes are local on your IDE), your changes should be under unstated/untracked files. You can confirm that if you run the `git status` command.

There is 3 options to undo the local changes you have on your IDE.

1. Discard all local changes, but save them for possible re-use later: `git stash`
2. Discard all local changes (permanently) to a file: `git checkout -- <file>`
3. Discard all local changes to all files permanently: `git reset --hard`

The last option is a dangerous command that you should avoid using if you are not sure what you are doing , since it removes all your uncommitted changes. However, in your case, that's what you seem to want to do.

For more information: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/numerous_undo_possibilities_in_git/#undo-local-changes

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not commit your changes, you can checkout the master branch and delete the new branch as you suggested. Alas, your uncommited changes will still be around! Since they were not commited in the first place, they just stick around in your working directory. To get rid of them, you have to reset your whole working directory with a command like `git reset --hard HEAD`. This will discard all changes and reset to the HEAD of your current branch (which would be `master`).

Comment: out if curiosity, if i create a new IDE environment and clone the repository, that would also work? or i would need to set up everything again like Git and Heroku?